# Choosing item in specific place from list of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, random

I have list of lists:

```
my_list = [['abc','defg','hij'],['klm','nopqrs','tuvw'],['xy','zabc','def'],['ghij','klmnop','qrs']]
```

I want to choose random list from all the lists and print the string in the 2nd location.

i tried:

```
for item in my_list:
    print(random.sample(item[1],len(item[1]))
```

Comment: do not use python keyword `list` for variable name. you need to make your random choice on a list level, and access the 2nd element of whatever is selected. you're instead doing it on an `item` level, and thus getting 1 letter.

Comment: Are those strings ("abc", "defg"....)? Also fix your typos (`choise`) and formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: yes, only strings

Comment: If you want to print the second string in **one** randomly picked list, then why do you have your `print` in a loop? And why do you reference `item[3]` (which is not the second string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chose a random index in `my_list` by using either with `random.randint` or `random.choice`. This:

```
from random import randint
list_choice = my_list[randint(0, len(my_list-1))]
```

and this:

```
from random import choice
list_choice = choice(my_list)
```

will both make `list_choice` have a random value from `my_list`. Then you can do this to print the second value in your list:

```
print(list_choice[1])
```

To make the numbers seem more random, you can use `random.seed` and `time.time` to set the random seed to the current time:

```
import random
import time

random.seed(time.time())
```

After doing all that, the full code should be this:

```
import random
import time

my_list = [['abc','defg','hij'],['klm','nopqrs','tuvw'],
           ['xy','zabc','def'],['ghij','klmnop','qrs']]

random.seed(time.time())
list_choice = random.choice(my_list)

print(list_choice[1])
```

Comment: After I chose a random list from all the lists i can't chose the 2nd item in the list. i recognize it as 1 string.

Comment: @Sig what happens when you try to?

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = [['abc','defg','hij'],['klm','nopqrs','tuvw'],['xy','zabc','def'],['ghij','klmnop','qrs']]
import random
print (random.choice(my_list)[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not iterate. Choose a random index and get your string result out present at that index.

```
import random
my_list = [['abc','defg','hij'],['klm','nopqrs','tuvw'],['xy','zabc','def'],['ghij','klmnop','qrs']]
random_index = random.randint(0, len(my_list) - 1) # will generate random index from range 0 to 3
word_index = 1
my_list [random_index][word_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down. Here's the list of lists:

```
my_lists = [
    ['abc', 'defg', 'hij'],
    ['klm', 'nopqrs', 'tuvw'],
    ['xy', 'zabc', 'def'],
    ['ghij', 'klmnop', 'qrs']
]
```

> I want to choose random list from all the lists

```
chosen_list = random.choice(my_lists)
```

> ... and print the string in the 2nd location.

```
print(chosen_list[1]) # remember Python uses zero-based indexing
```